# Double Discounted Lines in Shopify Order API

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I came across a situation that I hope someone else has seen.

The order looks like this in shopify:

[image: Screenshot]

The Discounted Line Item JSON looks like this:

```
      {
    "id": XXXXX,
    "name": "NAME",
    "price": "19.10",
    "product_exists": true,
    "quantity": 1,
    "sku": "SKU",
    "total_discount": "9.55",
    "discount_allocations": [
      {
        "amount": "9.55",
        "amount_set": {
          "shop_money": {
            "amount": "9.55",
            "currency_code": "USD"
          },
          "presentment_money": {
            "amount": "9.55",
            "currency_code": "USD"
          }
        },
        "discount_application_index": 0
      }
    ]
  },
```

An Automatic Discount as a "BOGO at 50% off" was applied to this order, but I cant quite get the discounting right for a net unit price, without also causing issues elsewhere in this particular Shopify Tenant.

Previously I would

```
line_unit_price = price - (TotalDiscount/Quantity) - SumOfDiscountApplications
```

But in this case, that would just double discount it to zero, which is not correct.  In other cases with this Shopify Tenant, I do need to use the Discount Applications as TotalDiscount would be 0. I cant quite figure out when/where/why to do the math differently for an effective Line Net Unit Price.

Very odd.  Any help would be great.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what exactly you're actually trying to accomplish here

Comment: The erp system we support needs a net of discounts unit price.  However if we look at what data we can use per-line in Shopify, I cant quite consistently calculate net unit price when a BOGO50%off promotion is used. I was hoping for others to know of a better way of handling this.

Comment: So you need the discount to be applied to both of the items, and have an accurate net price for each?

Comment: The challenge is that I do (Price - TotalDiscount - DiscountApplications) for all other others that have a mix of cart discounts, and line discounts. 

When we hit this type of BOGO50%Off type of discount, that math no longer works.

As a work around, we are left with comparing the estimated total versus the payment/transaction to see if we are close.

Comment: @IsraelLopez  did you find an answer to this I am facing the same problem